# The mean of cool-eyed

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

What does `cool-eyed` mean in the following sentence:

> The two young men strode freely up the aisle, confident and **cool-eyed**.

I have no any ideas to make sense of that construction.

Comment: +1 because at first I thought it's equal to *cold eyed* ;) Nevertheless, looking at the examples of this adjective, it seems that it's used to tell someone *marked with calmness.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched for the definition across the web but could not find the exact words. The search results give the reference of [WordHippo](http://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/words-that-rhyme-with/cool-eyed.html) and [WordLink](https://www.wordnik.com/words/cool-eyed) but both are blank inside.

So, *in my opinion*, it's taking the word *cool* as we know it! Also, the previous adjectives support what we **here** call *cool,* *cool!*

*Cool* refers to [calmness and relaxed state (#2)](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/cool). Having said this, the two men walked confidently and with calmness *(in their eyes?)*.

Worth noting that there's an adjective *[cold eyed](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cold-eyed)* (that I initially thought of) is different. One of the meanings for that is *not affected by emotions.* So, if the two men where *cold eyed*, they were probably rude! :)

Answer (score 2):

This could be interpreted two ways, depending on the context:

1. Not showing any emotion so as to not give away their fear, anger, trepidation, etc.
2. A treacherous and calculating look on their way to commit some unspeakable act.